# How to fix problem with array overload in while loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, while-loop

I'm trying to fix a SIGSEGV error in my program. I am not able to locate the site of error. The program compiles successfully in Xcode but does not provide me the results.

The goal of the program is to check whether the same element occurs in three separate arrays and return the element if it is more than 2 arrays.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int i = 0 ,j = 0,k = 0;
   int a[5]={23,30,42,57,90};
   int b[6]={21,23,35,57,90,92};
   int c[5]={21,23,30,57,90};
   while(i< 5 or j< 6 or  k< 5)
   {
       int current_a = 0;
       int current_b = 0;
       int current_c = 0;

       {   if (i<5) {
               current_a = a[i];
           } else
           {
               ;;
           }
           if (j<6)
           {
               current_b = b[j];
           } else
           {
               ;;
           }
           if (k<5)
           {
               current_c= c[k];
           } else
           {
               ;;
           }

       }
       int minvalue = min((current_a,current_b),current_c);
       int countoo = 0;

       if (minvalue==current_a)
       {
           countoo += 1;
           i++;
       }
       if (minvalue==current_b)
       {
           countoo +=1;
           j++;
       }
       if (minvalue==current_c)
       {
           countoo += 1;
           k++;
       }
       if (countoo >=2)
       {
           cout<< minvalue;
       }
   }
}
```

I am not getting any output for the code.

Comment: Could you please also show how your `a` `b` and `c` arrays are declared?

Comment: Actually, a [mcve] would be fine / required.

Comment: There is an obvious algorithmic error in your code, but in order to trace the segfault we need a [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnosch Can you please specify the algorithmic error? And how to provide minimal code without cutting out the essential information. Can you please elaborate. Thank you

Comment: `min((current_a,current_b),current_c)` is the same as `min(current_b,current_c)`. Read about how the comma works in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: I can and I did in an anwer below, which will become visible when you created a MCVE. Then I hope to pinpoint your segfault source to.

Comment: The explanation of how to make a MCVE is provided in the link you got in the comments.

Comment: @Yunnosch Can you please tell me if the code above is considered MCVE. I read the instructions.

Comment: Your indentaion is irritating, it often clouds the few on logical structures...

Comment: Be aware that a [mcve] does not have to solve your task! It only has to reproduce the problem, which is why it is actually required and your question is off-topic without one. Please, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Oh, and here's one more important tool to learn about:Step the code with a debugger!

Comment: I took some liberty with your indentation to help with analysis. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: Is `or` now an operator in recent C++?  Did I miss something?

Comment: @Yunnosch Actually I stand corrected: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative It seems this was a part of C++ for quite some time. Wow, that's insane that I didn't know about it.

Comment: @freakish I still appreciate your support. ;-)

Comment: Hello close-voters for lack of MCVE  (especially the one after OPs corresponding edit, @πάνταῥεῖ ). Are you sure? You did not perchance miss the fact that `or` DOES compile with recent C++? (according to freakish, I did admittedly not try myself).

Comment: Ikar anything still unclear? I mean apart from "How can I achieve the goal of the code?", for that please make a separate question. This one should stay "How to avoid segfault?"

Answer (score 1):

This is surely not doing what you want

```
int minvalue = min((current_a,current_b),current_c);
```

If `min()` is defined meaningfully (you really should provide an MCVE for a question like this), you want

```
int minvalue = min(min(current_a,current_b),current_c);
```

This will result in the minimum of the minimum of (a and b) and c, i.e. the minimum of all three, instead of the minimum of b and c. The comma operator `,` is important to understand this.

This seems to be a flag/counter to make a note across loop executions or count something

```
int countoo = 0;
```

It can however not work if you define the variable inside the loop.
You need to move that line BEFORE the `while`.

With this line you do not prevent the indexes to leave the size of the arrays,
that is very likely the source for the segfault.

```
while(i< 5 or j< 6 or  k< 5)
```

In order to prevent segfaults, make sure that ALL indexes stay small enough,
instead of only at least one.

```
while(i< 5 && j< 6 &&  k< 5)
```

(*By the way I initially seriously doubted that `or` can compile. I thought

with a macro for `or` it could, but I do not see that. It could be a new operator in a recent C++ standard update which I missed...
And it turns out that it is the case. I learned something here.*)

This should fix the segfault.
To achieve the goal of the code I think you need to spend some additional effort on the algorithm. I do not see the code being related to the goal.

Comment: I corrected the min function and my code now gives the expected (wanted) result, but succeeds it with zeros and shows SIGCOUNT error. Btw, I need the countoo to be inside the while loop as I need it to become zero before start of every loop and I need or statements within while not && statements because if an array is as follows a={53,55,57} b={52,53,57,59} c={53,57,59} I need it to count 59 despite of it being in only the b and c arrays.

Comment: I need the code to stop executing after all three arrays have reached their respective last element.

Comment: I think one possible solution is to make all the arrays the same size and then using && operator within the while loop. But I think I would need to use vectors for that.

Comment: If the segfault is avoided here, then this quesiton is answered. Please create separate new questions for further problems you have. Provide the new quesiton with a [mcve] of the changed code (do not edit here).

Comment: No there is a segcount error still. But the goal of the program has been achieved. That is the code gives the expected results succeeding with non ending zeroes and show segcount

Comment: Could be just me, but I do not know what "segcount" means, I only know about segfault and the usually accompanying SIGSEGV.